# transform navbar static to fixed when scroll bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have sample custom navbar and what I want is to make it fixed on top when it is scroll like this [**SAMPLE DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/118877)

here's mine.
[**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/C3AOOkNsUh)

Answer (score 1):

Paste this js code in js window in your demo.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.menu-x').affix({
                        offset: {
                        top: 0px
                        }
      }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippest to do this.Just add 'navbar-fixed-top' class in nav bar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height:1500px">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Fixed Navbar</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Scroll this page to see the effect</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This did not answer the question

Answer (score -1):

One simple way is to add `navbar-fixed-top` class.

More about it:

[Bootstrap-fixed-navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)

Updated code:

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/8hUiS8whTy)

Comment: sir output is wrong, the fixed navbar will take effect after scroll and the logo will become the navbar brand.

Comment: This did not answer the question